# ListChildren SQL Reporting Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a list of available reports via the webservice for SQL Reporting Services 2005 express edition.  Each time I try to call the ListChildren method I get an insuffient permission exception.  The code is:

`ReportingService2005SoapClient rService = new ReportingService2005SoapClient();
CatalogItem[] cItems = null;
rService.ListChildren("/", false, out cItems);`

I added the ASP.net (iusr) account into the local admin group on the PC and still get the exception.

Is this method supported in the express edition?

Mark

Comment: For those like me wondering where is ReportingService2005SoapClient defined, your must reference your ASMX service in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local admin group is not a part of SQL Server Administrators in SQL 2008 and I believe the same is true for SQL 2005 as well.

You can run the web service under a different domain account that has the priviledges, or in your SQL Reporting Services, add the `Computer\ASPNET` account as a user.